# Динамический GridLayoutManager. recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerviewadapter, gridlayoutmanager

Для работы приложения я использую `recyclerView`.
Возможно ли реализовать динамический `GridLayoutManager`, при котором при изменении размеров экрана телефона менялось и значение `spanCount`?

```
const val GRID_SPAN_COUNT = 3
private fun configureRecyclerView() {
    val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, GRID_SPAN_COUNT, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    val options = getFirestoreRecyclerOptions()
    adapter = NoticeAdapter(options, noticeViewModel)
    binding.recyclerViewNotice.layoutManager = layoutManager
    binding.recyclerViewNotice.adapter = adapter
}
```

Скрин приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне очень интересно как вы себе представляете изменение ширины экрана...    Речь про разделенный экран? В нем вроде запрещена смена ширины, даже в лэндскейпе либо пополам, либо никак. Какой случай вы хотите отловить?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что бывают телефоны с разными размерами дисплея, из-за чего gridCount c 3 строками не всегда будет уместен

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать вот это вот:

```
public class AutoFitGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

private int columnWidth;
private boolean columnWidthChanged = true;

public AutoFitGridLayoutManager(Context context, int columnWidth) {
    super(context, 1);

    setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
}

public void setColumnWidth(int newColumnWidth) {
    if (newColumnWidth > 0 && newColumnWidth != columnWidth) {
        columnWidth = newColumnWidth;
        columnWidthChanged = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (columnWidthChanged && columnWidth > 0) {
        int totalSpace;
        if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL) {
            totalSpace = getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - getPaddingLeft();
        } else {
            totalSpace = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        }
        int spanCount = Math.max(1, totalSpace / columnWidth);
        setSpanCount(spanCount);
        columnWidthChanged = true;
    }
    super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
}
```

}

Вот так вот:

```
      AutoFitGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new AutoFitGridLayoutManager(context, 800);
      recview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
```